# Envio Formulario por JavaScript Fetch y C# MVC

Tags: javascript, html, c#, fetch

Saludes a todos,

Tengo el sgte problema, etoy intentando enviar unformulario por Fetch a un controlador en c# MVC

Codigo HTML

```js
 document.getElementById('btnActualizarProveedor_Mod').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    actualizarProveedor();
  });

let actualizarProveedor = () => {
  let formDataModel = new FormData(document.getElementById('formModalEditarProveedor'));
  ShowFormData(formDataModel);

  fetch(RutaAplicacion + "Proveedores/ActualizaProveedor2", {
    type: 'POST',
    body: formDataModel
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
};
let ShowFormData = (formData) => {
  // Display the key/value pairs
  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
  }
}
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formModalEditarProveedor" id="formModalEditarProveedor">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="box-body">


            <input type="hidden" class="txt_prv_id" name="txt_prv_id_Mod_hidden" id="txt_prv_id_Mod_hidden" />
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>NIT: </label>
                  <input class="form-control txt_prv_nit_edit" name="txt_prv_nit_edit_Mod" id="txt_prv_nit_edit_Mod" type="text" readonly />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>CV: <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                  <input class="form-control txt_prv_cv_edit" name="txt_prv_cv_edit_Mod" id="txt_prv_cv_edit_Mod" type="text" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Proveedor: </label>
                  <input class="form-control txt_prv_proveedor_edit" name="txt_prv_proveedor_edit_Mod" id="txt_prv_proveedor_edit_Mod" type="text" readonly />

                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Cobertura:</label>
                  <input class="form-control txt_prv_cobertura_edit" name="txt_prv_cobertura_edit_Mod" id="txt_prv_cobertura_edit_Mod" type="text" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Categoria: <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                  <input class="form-control txt_prv_categoria_edit" name="txt_prv_categoria_edit_Mod" id="txt_prv_categoria_edit_Mod" type="text" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Dirección: </label>
                  <input class="form-control txt_prv_direccion_edit" name="txt_prv_direccion_edit_Mod" id="txt_prv_direccion_edit_Mod" type="text" readonly />

                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Contacto:</label>
                  <input class="form-control txt_prv_contacto_edit" name="txt_prv_contacto_edit_Mod" id="txt_prv_contacto_edit_Mod" type="text" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Celular: <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                  <input class="form-control txt_prv_celular_edit" name="txt_prv_celular_edit_Mod" id="txt_prv_celular_edit_Mod" type="text" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Telefono:</label>
                  <input class="form-control txt_prv_telefono_edit" name="txt_prv_telefono_edit_Mod" id="txt_prv_telefono_edit_Mod" type="text" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Telefono 2:</label>
                  <input class="form-control txt_prv_telefono2_edit" name="txt_prv_telefono2_edit_Mod" id="txt_prv_telefono2_edit_Mod" type="text" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Fax:</label>
                  <input class="form-control txt_prv_fax_edit" name="txt_prv_fax_edit_Mod" id="txt_prv_fax_edit_Mod" type="text" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Email: <span style="color:red">*</span></label>
                  <input class="form-control txt_prv_email_edit" name="txt_prv_email_edit_Mod" id="txt_prv_email_edit_Mod" type="text" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Email2:</label>
                  <input class="form-control txt_prv_email2_edit" name="txt_prv_email2_edit_Mod" id="txt_prv_email2_edit_Mod" type="text" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Plan de financiamiento:</label>
                  <input class="form-control txt_prv_plan_de_financiamiento_edit" name="txt_prv_plan_de_financiamiento_edit_Mod" id="txt_prv_plan_de_financiamiento_edit_Mod" type="text" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Observaciones:</label>
                  <input class="form-control txt_prv_observaciones_edit" name="txt_prv_observaciones_edit_Mod" id="txt_prv_observaciones_edit_Mod" type="text" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12  form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Camara de Comercial:</label>
                  <input type="file" class="fil_prv_camara_comercio_edit" name="fil_prv_camara_comercio_edit_Mod" id="fil_prv_camara_comercio_edit_Mod" />
                  <input type="hidden" class="txt_prv_camara_comercio" name="txt_prv_camara_comercio_Mod_hidden" id="txt_prv_camara_comercio_Mod_hidden" value="" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12  form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Rut:</label>
                  <input type="file" class="fil_prv_rut_edit" name="fil_prv_rut_edit_Mod" id="fil_prv_rut_edit_Mod" />
                  <input type="hidden" class="prv_rut" value="" name="prv_rut_Mod_hidden" id="prv_rut_Mod_hidden" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12  form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Certificación Contrato:</label>
                  <input type="file" class="fil_prv_certificacion_edit" name="fil_prv_certificacion_edit_Mod" id="fil_prv_certificacion_edit_Mod" />
                  <input type="hidden" class="txt_prv_certificacion" value="" name="txt_prv_certificacion_Mod_hidden" id="txt_prv_certificacion_Mod_hidden" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12  form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Formato Proveedor:</label>
                  <input type="file" class="fil_prv_formato_proveedor_edit" name="fil_prv_formato_proveedor_edit_Mod" id="fil_prv_formato_proveedor_edit_Mod" />
                  <input type="hidden" class="txt_prv_formato_proveedor" value="" name="txt_prv_formato_proveedor_Mod_hidden" id="txt_prv_formato_proveedor_Mod_hidden" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12  form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Cedula:</label>
                  <input type="file" class="fil_prv_cedula_edit" name="fil_prv_cedula_edit_Mod" id="fil_prv_cedula_edit_Mod" />
                  <input type="hidden" class="txt_prv_cedula" value="" name="txt_prv_cedula_Mod_hidden" id="txt_prv_cedula_Mod_hidden" />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12  form-group">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Certificaciones Bancarias:</label>
                  <input type="file" class="fil_prv_certificaciones_edit" name="fil_prv_certificaciones_edit_Mod" id="fil_prv_certificaciones_edit_Mod" />
                  <input type="hidden" class="txt_prv_certificaciones" value="" name="txt_prv_certificaciones_Mod_hidden" id="txt_prv_certificaciones_Mod_hidden" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--=====================================
        PIE DEL MODAL
        ======================================-->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btnActualizarProveedor" name="btnActualizarProveedor_Mod" id="btnActualizarProveedor_Mod">
            Guardar Cambios
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Codigo c#

En El controlador tengo este método q' recibe la la data

```
[HttpPost]
public JObject ActualizaProveedor2(ProvClass editProveedor)
{
        recordsJson.Add(new JProperty("respuesta", "Ok"));
        return recordsJson;
}
```

Los campos q reciben los archivos los declaro como    HttpPostedFileWrapper
por ejemplo:

```
public partial class ProvClass
{
    public int txt_prv_id_Mod_hidden { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_nit_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_cv_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_cobertura_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_proveedor_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_categoria_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_direccion_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_contacto_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_celular_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_telefono_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_telefono2_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_fax_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_email_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_email2_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_plan_de_financiamiento_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_observaciones_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    //Type File
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileWrapper fil_prv_camara_comercio_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_camara_comercio_Mod_hidden { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileWrapper fil_prv_rut_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string prv_rut_Mod_hidden { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileWrapper fil_prv_certificacion_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_certificacion_Mod_hidden { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileWrapper fil_prv_formato_proveedor_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_formato_proveedor_Mod_hidden { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileWrapper fil_prv_cedula_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_cedula_Mod_hidden { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileWrapper fil_prv_certificaciones_edit_Mod { get; set; }
    public string txt_prv_certificaciones_Mod_hidden { get; set; }
    ///////////////////////////////////////

    public string prv_calificacion { get; set; }
    public string prv_usuario { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime prv_fec_registro { get; set; }
    public int prv_est_id { get; set; }

    public virtual estado estado { get; set; }
}
```

Mas sin Embargo el error q me aparece es:

```
TypeError: HEAD or GET Request cannot have a body.
```

De acuerdo a la documentación [Fetch Documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch) 
Fetch automáticamente detecta y coloca la cabecera.

Mas noto q ni siquiera realiza el envió.

Cuando valido la información q carga la variable formDataModel me indica q' obtiene la información correctamente:

Este es el contenido de formDataModel

txt_prv_id_Mod_hidden,
txt_prv_nit_edit_Mod, 4831 
txt_prv_cv_edit_Mod, 
txt_prv_proveedor_edit_Mod, BULLA ORJUELA HERNANDO 
txt_prv_cobertura_edit_Mod, 
txt_prv_categoria_edit_Mod, 
txt_prv_direccion_edit_Mod, 
txt_prv_contacto_edit_Mod, 
txt_prv_celular_edit_Mod, 
txt_prv_telefono_edit_Mod, 
txt_prv_telefono2_edit_Mod, 
txt_prv_fax_edit_Mod, 
txt_prv_email_edit_Mod, 
txt_prv_email2_edit_Mod, 
txt_prv_plan_de_financiamiento_edit_Mod,
txt_prv_observaciones_edit_Mod, INCUMPLIMIENTO 
fil_prv_camara_comercio_edit_Mod, [object File]
txt_prv_camara_comercio_Mod_hidden, data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcNCiX6+/z9DQ...
fil_prv_rut_edit_Mod, [object File] proveedores.js:1036:5
prv_rut_Mod_hidden, data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcNCiX6+/z9D...
fil_prv_certificacion_edit_Mod, [object File] proveedores.js:1036:5
txt_prv_certificacion_Mod_hidden, data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcNCiX6+/z9DQ...
fil_prv_formato_proveedor_edit_Mod, [object File] 
txt_prv_formato_proveedor_Mod_hidden, data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcNCiX6+/z9DQo...
fil_prv_cedula_edit_Mod, [object File] 
txt_prv_cedula_Mod_hidden, data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcNCiX6+/z9DQox...

Si a alguien le ha pasado le agradezco, quisiera utilizar esta opción con FETCH y no tener q recurrir a JQuery.

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es al momento de enviar la petición. Deberás cambiar `type: 'POST',`, por `method: 'POST',` para que puedas enviarla como deseas:

```
fetch(RutaAplicacion + "Proveedores/ActualizaProveedor2", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formDataModel
})
```

Si no especificas un método, por default se toma como `GET`, es por eso el error que te muestra.

Comment: Tal cual dices compañero, era un error "elemental", al corregirlo esta opción me funciono. Aunq' me esta generando unos problemas de compatibilidad pero ya eso es otro asunto. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Otra solución q encontré para no utilizar Jquery fue la sgte por si a alguien le sirve.

```
`var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("POST", RutaAplicacion + "Proveedores/ActualizaProveedor2", true);
xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) { UploadProgress(evt); }, false);
xhr.addEventListener("load", function (evt) { UploadComplete(evt); }, false);
xhr.addEventListener("error", function (evt) { UploadFailed(evt); }, false);
xhr.addEventListener("abort", function (evt) { UploadFailed(evt); }, false);
xhr.send(formDataModel);`
```

Gracias.